# Getting the value of dynamic text pass it to input value

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is the dynamic list that i created and i want to pass it to input value.
Here's my code.

```
 <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","dbStudent");
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from tblaccounts");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
    {
    ?>
    <ul>
    <li onclick="GettingSurname" id="Surname"><?php echo $row["Lastname"]; ?></li>
    </ul>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
```

It will display in input value if i clicked the surname.

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
```

If i selected the the surname it will pass it to input value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GettingSurname()
    {
       document.getElementById("username").value = Surname;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You forgot `()` use `onclick="GettingSurname()"`

Comment: Where do you define `Surname`, which you are using in the `GettingSurname()`-function? Btw, shouldn't you have the `<ul>` before the loop and `</ul>` after the loop? Otherwise, you're just creating a new list, containing only one item for each user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you what to pass the text content of `li` as text of username, You need to pass the current element i.e. `this` to inline event handler. use `textContent` property to set value.

```
<li onclick="GettingSurname(this)"><?php echo $row["Lastname"]; ?></li>
```

Script

```
function GettingSurname(elem)
{
   document.getElementById("username").value = elem.textContent;
}
```

Note: You are creating element with same id `id="Surname"`, In HTML identifiers must be **unique**

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be creating the row in a while loop, so this could end up with creating multiple rows with the same id (surname). Instead you can just pass the name in as a parameter in the function like this:

```
<li onclick="GettingSurname('<?php echo json_encode($row["Lastname"]); ?>')"><?php echo $row["Lastname"]; ?></li>
```

(make sure you encode the surname in the function parameter just in case someone is called o'connor or if someone puts xss hack as their surname)

then in the javascript do this:

```
function GettingSurname(surname){ 
 document.getElementById("username").value = surname;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another and a more better way to achieve the same goal is:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","dbStudent");
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from tblaccounts");

//Take a counter variable to assign dynamic IDs to the HTML element iterated in the while loop
$counter = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
{
    ?>
    <ul>
        <li onclick="GettingSurname('<?php echo $row["Lastname"]; ?>')" id="Surname_<?php echo $counter; ?>">
            <?php echo $row["Lastname"]; ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
<?php 
    $counter++;
}
?>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GettingSurname(surname_value)
{
    document.getElementById("username").value = surname_value;
}
</script>
```